# Set CSS vars in angular material (e.g. --mat-standard-button-toggle-height)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-theming

I'm customizing the angular material theme and found the CSS vars for the values I want to customize.Now my SCSS for customizing looks like this:

```
:root {
  --mat-standard-button-toggle-selected-state-background-color: #{$color-primary};
  --mat-standard-button-toggle-selected-state-text-color: #{$color-font-light};
  --mat-standard-button-toggle-height: 44px;
}
```

This does not look very pretty. What would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming this is the recommended way on how to theme angular material. But as long as it works for you, you can do whatever you want of course.

Comment: But this does not describe how I can set the values I defined above :/

Comment: I never themed angular material, but if they don't provide an option to do it then you have to do it one by one as you are already doing it. I think in their theming you can define base-colors and all colors are calculated based off of the base colors.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. after searching since forever, I haven't found anything better. The theming gives me the ilusion, that there is this sufisticated customization scheme behind it, but if you try to customize anything, you end up overwriting css classes.

Comment: Maybe you can check their SCSS files and see how they build the variables. Maybe you can call their functions with your own colors. But this is most probably not documented, you have to try and see if this works for you.